Any orthographic and pronunciation rules for e followed by a vowel?
Consulting various sites  I have compiled the following list or rules for the spelling and pronunciation of e:
La distribution de /e/ et /ɛ/ suit plus ou moins la Loi de position, c'est-à-dire que /e/ se trouve toujours en syllabe ouverte (aller = [ale]) et que /ɛ/ se trouve souvent en syllabe fermée (belle = [bɛl]). Toutefois, il y a des exceptions. Dans la plupart des cas, l'orthographe permet de choisir la bonne voyelle (voir ci-dessous).
Orthographe
L'orthographe de /e/
La voyelle /e/ est représentée par les lettres "e" ou "ai" dans certains contextes:
OR 1  tout ce qui s'écrit avec "é", par ex.: allé [ale], fée [fe].
OR 2  les mots qui se terminent en une consonne muette autre que "T" ou "N", par ex.: manger [mãʒe], nez, [ne], pied [pje], etc. (non-example: effet [efɛ].)
OR 3  dans la conjonction et [e] (avec le sens de "and")
OR 4  les verbes qui se terminent en "ai(e)", par ex.: j'ai [ʒe], j'irai /[iʁe].
OR 5  "e" suive (followed)d'une lettre double, par ex.: dessert [desɛʁ], effet [efɛ].
L'orthographe de /ɛ/
La voyelle /ɛ/ est représentée par les lettres "e" ou "ai" dans certains contextes:
OR 6 "e" en syllabe fermée, par ex.: belle [bɛl], mettent [mɛt].
OR 7 les mots qui s'écrivent avec "è" ou "ê", par ex.: très [tʁɛ], bête [bɛt].
OR 8 "ai" suivi (followed) d'une consonne non-nasale et muette, par ex.: j'irais [ʒiʁɛ], il parlait [ilpaʁlɛ].
OR 9 les noms et adjectifs qui se terminent en "ai(e)", par ex.: mai [mɛ], vrai [vʁɛ].
OR 10 "e" + "t", "st" ou "ct", par ex.: jouet /ʒwɛ/, billet [bijɛ], respect [ʁɛspɛ], est/ɛ/
Spelling rules
You can boil it down to a several rules but to some extent you'll need to know if the word has schwa or a full vowel (this explains the alternation between mener and mène vs céder et cède for example, mener has z schwa and céder a full vowel, even if mène and cède have the same vowel)
**What is a full vowel ?:In French, a full vowel does not depend on stress but instead on whether the vowel is pronounced clearly and distinctly. Stress in French, while typically on the final syllable, does not affect the clarity of earlier vowels. Therefore, the é in éducation is a full vowel because it is pronounced as /e/, while the e in Angleterre is not, as it is reduced to a schwa (/ə/).
Simply put all vowels except the schwa (/ə/) are full vowels
SR 1 Schwa is always written e and either word final or followed by a single consonant (digraphs like ch or gn count as single consonants) then another vowel.
SR 2 If e is followed by several consonants it's always a full vowel and no diacritic is ever used. "x" counts as several consonants.
2b. Note: groups of consonants and l or r, it counts as a single consonant: chevrotain \ʃə.vʁɔ.tɛ̃\ has a schwa ( vr is consider a single consonant so the e is not necessarily a full vowel) while lévrier has a full vowel for example (if they followed the normal consonant cluster rules, both words would have no diacritic and be pronounced with as full vowel)
SR 3. If a word has "ess" it's ambiguous: message (\me.saʒ\ ou \mɛ.saʒ)and ressac (\ʁə.sak) don't have the same vowel. But in spelling, there will never be a diacritic to disambiguate the two.
SR 4. If e is a full vowel followed by a single consonant (or a digraph) followed by another vowel that isn't schwa, it's always written é.  e.g. éducation, réaction, déviation.
SR 5. If e is a full vowel followed by a single consonant (or a digraph) followed by another vowel that is a schwa, it's always written è.[* silent final e is considered a schwa since the people that pronounce it do it as a schwa]
e.g. mène (leads), crèche (nursery), grève (strike)
SR 6. Exception: if e is part of a prefix like pré- or dé- it is written with é (as in détenu or prévenir for example)
e.g. prévenir (to warn)[ \pʁev.niʁ\ ou \pʁe.və.niʁ], détenu[\det.ny] (detained).
SR 7. If a word begins with e, it will always be written é if followed by a single consonant and e if followed by multiple consonants or a digraph: évite, élever, espace, essence
SR 8. If e is the last letter in a word, it's written é if it's a full vowel, and e if it's schwa e.g. café (coffee, full vowel), musée (museum, full vowel), libre (free, schwa), chaude (hot, schwa) .[* silent final e is considered a schwa since the are people that do pronounce it it as a schwa]
SR 9. If e is the last vowel in a word, followed by one or several consonants, it's always written without a diacritic.
e.g. mer (sea), tel (such), sec (dry)
SR 10. Exception: if the consonant is s, the vowel can be written é, è or e depending on pronunciation.
"é": dés (dice), près (near).
No accent: mes (my), les (the).
My question:
I am coming across words that don't follow any of these rules such as:
"la géographie \ʒe.ɔ.ɡʁa.fi, le lycée"\li.se, Montréal\mɔ̃.ʁe.al\  , Néerlandais
So basically that's when it's followed by another vowel. I have searched a lot of sites, but none of them discusses this, I mean rules on how to pronounce (full open, full closed or schwa ) and/or written ( i.e with diacritic or not) "e" when it is followed by another vowel. Do you know any? +1 if you can provide a reference.
In particular why is it "é" in the  examples above?

You could cite the site where you found these rules.


When e is preceded by g and followed by any vowel, the e is unpronounced. The e is only there for g to be pronounced as /ʒ/.

ea:
If followed by u, pronounced /o/.
Otherwise, only found in borrowed foreign words. Pronounced /ɛ/ (ex: un steak) or /i/ (clean).

éa:
Pronounced /e.a/

ee:
Is only found in foreign words and pronounced /i/ (ex: un weekend)

ée:
Pronounced /e/ unless the e is followed by a consonant (ex: /e.ɛ/ in néerlandais, /e.e/ in créer). Still a single /e/ in some words like créerons or féerie (or not).

éé:
Pronounced /e.e/

éi:
Pronounced /e.i/

ei:
Pronounced /ɛ/, /ɛj/, /e/ or /œ/ depending on the context. (ex: neige, soleil, conseiller, accueil /akœj/)

eo:
e is not pronounced in asseoir, surseoir, etc.
Otherwise, pronounced /e.o/ or /i/. Only occurs in a few foreign words (deo, paseo / people).

éo:
Always pronounced /e.o/, /e.ɔ/ or /e/ + something if o is part of a digraph like ou or on

eu:
Pronounced either /ø/ or /œ/ (except in gageure because of the g and in past forms of avoir : eu, eut, eusse, etc.)

éu:
Pronounced /e.y/

ey:
Pronounced /ɛ/ or /ɛj/ when followed by another vowel.


There doesn't seem to be examples of words where è, ê or ë are followed by a vowel in French.
Note also that regional variations might exist between whether /e/ or /ɛ/ is used.

Should I assume è+vowel never occurs?

@some_math_guy I believe so, nor ê+vowel and ë+vowel.

I pronounce créerons and féerie as /e.ɛ/, like in Néerlandais. I pronounce ils créent as /e/.

@FrançoisJurain Nobody's perfect ;-)

Which I should pronouce pierfect for good measure.

@FrançoisJurain To be honest, I often pronounce féerie with /e.e/ but never with /e.ɛ/. That last one sounds like Ferrari to my ears.

Any idea why do we need a final e in ée ? According to my rules a final e is either a schwa, written e or a full vowel, written é and therefore pronounced/e/ so ée makes no difference, it is still /e/

@some_math_guy Most if not all -ée are feminine nouns/adjectives/past participles while -é are masculine.

Isn't there any rule that tell me how I should write the homophones based on the other letters like if I hear /e.o/, I wouldn't know when it is géo or geo ; for example géographie or geographie

Is there any reference for you answer?

@some_math_guy I'm pretty sure there's always an accent in éo if the e is pronounced. If there's no accent, it means the e is silent, usually after a g to make it soft (pigeon, flageolet, etc).

Yes, if géographie was written as geographie, it would theoretically be pronounced like jographie. There are no examples of French words starting with geo- but for example geai is pronounced /ʒɛ/ like jet or j'ai are also commonly pronounced.  Note that geisha is pronounced /geʃa/ or / gejʃa/.
